# Spring MVC tutorial project does not build on IntelliJ

Tags: java, spring, maven, intellij-idea

I am trying to build and run a Spring MVC beginner lesson project using IntelliJ. I imported the existing project from GitHub. But when I try to build the project I keep getting:

```
Error:(3, 38) java: package org.springframework.stereotype does not exist
Error:(4, 47) java: package org.springframework.web.bind.annotation does not exist
```

These external dependencies jars are under my Maven local repositories (C:\Users\sudi.m2)and I can see in IntelliJ under Maven->Repositories that repo location is indeed there. I also tried "Invalidate Cache and restart" but that does not help. My M2_HOME is set correctly to C:\apache-maven-3.2.2. If I try to run mvn install from command line, I get:

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 40.845 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-09-25T19:03:21+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 9M/93M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.2:war    (default-war) on project basic-web-app: Error assembling WAR: webxml attribute is required    (or preexisting WEB-INF/web.xml if executing in update mode) -> [Help 1]
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: where is ur web.xml placed in your project?/

Comment: web.xml is under webapp/WEB-INF

Comment: I was running mvn install from the wrong location. I ran it from the correct location and that compiles the java file successfully and builds the war. But it does not work from only within the IntelliJ IDE

Comment: If you have this problem with Gradle - look at the last block of your build.gradle - it conatins version of Gradle. You need this version installed on your PC and you need add Gradle to Path.

Answer (score 1):

If the project doesn't have a web.xml file (IE: Entirely java config based). The build war plugin will fail unless you specify the "failOnMissingWebXml" attribute to false.

Comment: Can you link to the github project or is it private?

Comment: I was running mvn install from the wrong location. I ran it from the correct location and that compiles the java file successfully and builds the war. But it does not work from only within the IntelliJ IDE.

Comment: Thats a private project, I just cloned it on my desktop and imported the project into IntelliJ.

Comment: @sudi Go to View -> Tool Windows -> Maven Project. In the window that pops up, click the execute maven goal icon. In the 'Command line' field, type in 'clean install'. Hit ok.

Comment: that builds the entire project fine, thanks for your tip. But if I try to compile the single java file by itself, it still gives the compile errors! Any ideas?

Comment: @sudi Well, you shouldn't be able to compile a single class if it has references to others. IE: Should return a "Cannot find symbol exception". If you're getting other errors, IntelliJ should point out what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Delete you local .m2 repository and let it re-download all needed jars. Maybe, there were issues while downloading one of the dependencies.

Comment: I did that and see the same problem but don't think that should be the problem as it seems to be a problem finding the dependency itself rather than any inherent problem with the dependency.